# File naming conventions

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions, entity

Please help me for the naming of the class file that defines the property of each value (Entity class). Example: for a dataset file we will use the name like this: dsxxx. But i don't know what will for entity class Please help me for that. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Entity Class has no naming convention. Normaly you'll call it like that what it is.

e.g 
Company.cs  -> Entity class for the Company

But you can distinct it, because other "entity like" classes have naming conventions.

e.g.

```
CompanyViewModel.cs -> View Model for the entity class
ICompany.cs -> Interface for the Company Entity
CompanyDto -> Data Transfer Object
```

etc